# Why does OS X Mountain Lion ask for my password when I duplicate a file?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-mountain-lion, finder

When I use Finder to do this:
- right click file
- choose "duplicate"

I get asked for my password. Every. Single. Time.

I have tried every trick I could find online, up to and including repairing ACL permissions (http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/how_to_resolve_user-level_permissions_issues_mac_os_x). Still no luck.

I use this feature a lot, and would very much like to het rid of the password prompt.

P.S. I have FileVault enabled

Comment: I think this question already discussed in here
http://superuser.com/questions/313845/why-does-os-x-lion-ask-for-my-password-whenever-i-delete-a-file-in-my-home-direc Also, take a look in here
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4216838?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: I have tried everything in those posts. Completely baffled. If I copy and paste on the Desktop, the file is duplicated, no problem. If I use Finder, right click, Duplicate, I get the password prompt. I have checked permissions of /private/tmp and all ACL's. The demo user I have on my MacBook does not have this problem. I may just make a new user and be done with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer here: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1577363

Somehow, "Duplicate exactly" has become the default command rather than "Duplicate".

And "Duplicate exactly" seems to require authentication.

Running `defaults delete -g` from Terminal and killing all Finder instances solved this for me.